# How to solve library dependency betwee app and src folder?

Tags: c++, cmake, cmakelists-options

I have a project that contains the `src` and `app` folder. Each folder contains a `CMakeLists.txt` file. The project has a single `CMakeLists.txt` file that is currently `add_subdirectory`ing the `src` folder. This general `CMakeLists.txt` generates a `dll` and `lib` with the code from the `src` folder and installs it.

The problem is that the `app` has a `CMakeLists.txt` file that compiles a class that uses the library that was installed when running the `src` folder.

1. How to configure the `CMakeLists.txt` in the `app` folder to use the library that was created and installed when running the `CMakeLists.txt` from the `src` folder?
2. Can the `CMakeLists.txt` in the `app` folder be called from the general `CMakeLists.txt`? Or should a create a fully separate `CMAkeLIsts.txt` in the `app` folder?

General `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.15..3.25 FATAL_ERROR )

# Create Project
project( "myproject"
        VERSION 0.1
        LANGUAGES CXX)
set(LIBRARY_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME}_lib)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR include)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR lib)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR bin)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX $ENV{OCTREE_HOME})
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "$ENV{PCL_ROOT}/cmake/Modules/" "$ENV{OCTREE_HOME}/share/cmake/Modules/")

message(STATUS "CMAKE_MODULE_PATH: ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}")

# All users of this library will need at least C++11
if(MSVC)
    add_compile_options(/Zc:__cplusplus)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /std:c++latest /bigobj")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
else(MSVC)
    target_compile_features(apps PUBLIC cxx_std_17)
endif(MSVC)

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -g")
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

# find packages
set(OpenCV_DIR "${VCPKG_INSTALLED_DIR}/x86-windows/share/opencv3")
find_package(OpenCV CONFIG REQUIRED) # COMPONENTS opencv_world)
if (OpenCV_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "OpenCV version: ${OpenCV_VERSION}")
endif()

option(USE_PCL "Use PCL" ON)
find_package(PCL CONFIG REQUIRED COMPONENTS common io filters visualization)
if (PCL_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "PCL version: ${PCL_VERSION}")
    add_definitions(-DPOINTCLOUDREAD_USES_PCL)
endif()

# The executable code is here
add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(apps)

#Install the targets and their associated files
install(TARGETS ${LIBRARY_NAME}
        LIBRARY DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}"
        INCLUDES DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}"
        PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}"
        RUNTIME DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}"
        )
install(TARGETS ${LIBRARY_NAME} DESTINATION "$ENV{OCTREE_HOME}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}")
install(TARGETS ${LIBRARY_NAME} LIBRARY DESTINATION "$ENV{OCTREE_HOME}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}")
install(DIRECTORY include/ DESTINATION "$ENV{OCTREE_HOME}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}")
install(FILES cmake/Modules/Find${PROJECT_NAME}.cmake DESTINATION "$ENV{OCTREE_HOME}/share/cmake/Modules/")
```

`src` CMakeLists.txt

```
set(PROJECT_INCLUDE_DIRS ${CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY}/include)
set(HEADER_LIST ../include/octreesegmentation.h ../include/templates.h)
set(SOURCE_LIST ../src/octreesegmentation.cpp)
list(APPEND INCLUDE_DIRS
        "${EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR}"
        "${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}"
        "${PROJECT_INCLUDE_DIR}"
        "${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}"
        "$ENV{PCL_ROOT}/3rdParty/VTK/include/vtk-${VTK_MAJOR_VERSION}.${VTK_MINOR_VERSION}"
        "${PROCESSING_INCLUDE_DIRS}"
        "${PROJECT_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
list(APPEND TARGET_LINK_LIB_DIRS
        "$ENV{OCTREE_HOME}/lib"
        "${OpenCV_DIR}/${OpenCV_ARCH}/${OpenCV_RUNTIME}/lib"
        "${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS}"
        "${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS}/../3rdParty/VTK/lib"
        "${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS}/../3rdParty/Eigen/lib"
        "$ENV{OCTREE_HOME}/lib")
list(APPEND TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES
        "${OpenCV_LIBS}"
        "${PCL_LIBRARIES}"
        "${PCL_VISUALIZATION_LIBRARIES}"
        "${PREPROCESSING_LIBRARIES}"
        "${PROCESSING_LIBRARIES}"
        "${POSTPROCESSING_LIBRARIES}"
        "${PCL_COMMON_LIBRARY_DEBUG}"
        "VTK::CommonCore")

if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Debug)
    message(STATUS "========================== DEBUG INFO ==========================")
    message(STATUS "HEADER_LIST: ${HEADER_LIST}")
    message(STATUS "SOURCE_LIST: ${SOURCE_LIST}")
    message(STATUS "INCLUDE_DIRS: ${INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    message(STATUS "TARGET_LINK_LIB_DIRS: ${TARGET_LINK_LIB_DIRS}")
    message(STATUS "TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES: ${TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES}")
    message(STATUS "========================== END OF DEBUG INFO ==========================")
endif()

# Generate LIB file
add_library(${LIBRARY_NAME} STATIC ${SOURCE_LIST} ${HEADER_LIST})
set_target_properties(${LIBRARY_NAME} PROPERTIES
        VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
        OUTPUT_NAME ${LIBRARY_NAME}
        ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY}/lib)

target_include_directories(${LIBRARY_NAME} PUBLIC ${INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_directories(${LIBRARY_NAME} PRIVATE ${TARGET_LINK_LIB_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${LIBRARY_NAME} PRIVATE ${TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES})


# Generate DLL file
add_library(${LIBRARY_NAME}_dll SHARED ${SOURCE_LIST} ${HEADER_LIST})
set_target_properties(${LIBRARY_NAME}_dll PROPERTIES
        VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
        OUTPUT_NAME ${LIBRARY_NAME}
        LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY}/lib)

target_include_directories(${LIBRARY_NAME} PUBLIC ${INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_directories(${LIBRARY_NAME} PRIVATE ${TARGET_LINK_LIB_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${LIBRARY_NAME} PRIVATE ${TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES})
```

`app` CMakeLists.txt. This CMakeLists.txt should use the library that is generated in the `src` folder.

```
list(APPEND INCLUDE_DIRS
        "${EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR}"
        "${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}"
        "${PROJECT_INCLUDE_DIR}"
        "${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}"
        "$ENV{PCL_ROOT}/3rdParty/VTK/include/vtk-${VTK_MAJOR_VERSION}.${VTK_MINOR_VERSION}"
        "${PROCESSING_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
list(APPEND TARGET_LINK_LIB_DIRS
        "$ENV{OCTREE_HOME}/lib"
        "${OpenCV_DIR}/${OpenCV_ARCH}/${OpenCV_RUNTIME}/lib"
        "${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS}"
        "${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS}/../3rdParty/VTK/lib"
        "${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS}/../3rdParty/Eigen/lib")
list(APPEND TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES
        "${OCTREESEGMENTATION_LIBRARIES}"
        "${OpenCV_LIBS}"
        "${PCL_LIBRARIES}"
        "${PCL_VISUALIZATION_LIBRARIES}"
        "${PREPROCESSING_LIBRARIES}"
        "${PROCESSING_LIBRARIES}"
        "${POSTPROCESSING_LIBRARIES}"
        "${PCL_COMMON_LIBRARY_DEBUG}"
        "VTK::CommonCore"
        "VTK::SystemTools")
include_directories("${INCLUDE_DIRS}" )
link_directories(${TARGET_LINK_LIB_DIRS})
#add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
#add_library(main SHARED ${PROCESSING_SOURCES})
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main ${OCTREESEGMENTATION_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: The application should just be able to link to the library target, have you tried it? What problem did you encounter? Please show a [mre]

Comment: "Can the `CMakeLists.txt` in the app folder be called from the general `CMakeLists.txt`?" - Yes, you may do that. Just use appropriate `add_subdirectory` call. If you want to build `app` and `src` separately (with **separate invocations** of `cmake`), then `app` could use `find_package` for locate the installed library. For being "locatable", your library project should create a "config-file package". CMake documentation has examples of such packages, e.g. [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#creating-packages).

Comment: Without the code you explanations are very vague. Even the problem is unclear.

Comment: The CMakeLists.txt have been include for better understanding.

Comment: So, what is wrong with simple `target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE ${LIBRARY_NAME})`?

Answer (score 0):

You have two routes.

- Make `app` a standalone project. That means you need to call `cmake_minimum_required(...)` and `project()` and anything else you'd want in your project configuration such as the `CMAKE_*` variables you want to set. Then either write your `src` project to export a find config script (see also [the `CMakePackageConfigHelpers` module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakePackageConfigHelpers.html)) and find it via `find_package`, or `include` [the exported targets file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#export) from the installation, or [from the build tree if you use `export()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/export.html).
- Make the project that does `add_subdirectory(src ...)` also `add_subdirectory(app ...)`. See also [the `add_subdirectory` docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_subdirectory.html).

---

Misc other feedback:

- It's better to `list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ...)` instead of `set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ...)` in CMakeLists.txt so that you don't overwrite any value set by the user on the commandline.
- I think you'd be interested in [the `GNUInstallDirs` module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GNUInstallDirs.html)